# How to combine four foreach into one foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to add four foreach into one foreach. I don't know how but i'm trying like this. Here is an example :

```
 $images = "image1,image2,image3";
 $covers = "cover1,cover2,cover3";
 $titles = "title1,title2,title3";
 $albums = "album1,album2,album3";

 $images = explode(',', $images);
 $covers = explode(',', $covers);
 $titles = explode(',', $titles);
 $albums = explode(',', $albums);

 foreach (array_combine($images, $covers) as $image => $cover) {

 foreach (array_combine($titles, $albums) as $title => $album) {

 echo "$image - $cover - $title - $album</br>";        }}
```

But output is :

```
image1 - cover1 - title1 - album1
image1 - cover1 - title2 - album2
image1 - cover1 - title3 - album3
image2 - cover2 - title1 - album1
image2 - cover2 - title2 - album2
image2 - cover2 - title3 - album3
image3 - cover3 - title1 - album1
image3 - cover3 - title2 - album2
image3 - cover3 - title3 - album3
```

Need output :

```
image1 - cover1 - title1 - album1
image2 - cover2 - title2 - album2
image3 - cover3 - title3 - album3
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do. Why do a `foreach` loop at all, when a `for` loop with an index is so much simpler?

Comment: Have a look at the given answer in your previous question.

Comment: I don't know. Can you add example?

Comment: @Dows - I meant Nathans answer using a class to represent all 4 values. What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: Sorry i'm new in php so don't know i want any easy way to combile all 4 into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer Nathans answer in the previous question, he stores all 4 values in an object and iterates the objects.

If you really need those arrays, why not just use a normal `for` loop, it is made for such cases where you need the index and it may even be a bit more readable?

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($images); $index++)
{
  echo "$images[$index] - $covers[$index] - $titles[$index] - $albums[$index]</br>";  
}
```

P.S.

Instead of exploding the string, you could just build the array directly like this:

```
$images = array('image1', 'image2', 'image3');
```

Comment: Thanks working. @martinstoeckli

Comment: I think this is easy way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and loop through all 4 arrays, e.g.

```
array_map(function($v1, $v2, $v3, $4){
    echo "$v1 - $v2 - $v3 - $v4</br>";
}, $images, $covers, $titles, $albums);
```

Note, that you don't need all 4 arrays to be the same size.

Comment: minor typo there - it should be $v4 in function args rather than v$4

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks for the hint, that happens when you code fast in the editor.

Comment: Thanks working. @Rizier123

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way

```
 foreach($covers as $key=>$cover){
    echo $images[$key]."-".$cover ."-".$titles[$key]."-".$albums[$key]."<br/>";
 }
```